# New Event in existing/enabled module not showing in web profiler

Tags: 8

I have added an Event to an existing, and already enabled, module.  I'm including the relevant code below without comments for brevity.

```
  namespace Drupal\my_module\Event;
  final class MyModuleEvents {

  /**
   * @Event
   */
   const NUMBER_CODE_VERIFIED = 'my_module.number_code_verified';

  /**
   * @Event
   * THIS IS THE NEW ONE
   */
   const INCOMING_INIT = 'my_module.incoming_init';
  }
```

Here is the Event

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Event;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class MyModuleIncomingInit extends Event {

  protected $request;
  protected $type;

  public function __construct(Request $request, $type) {
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->type = $type;
  }
  public function getRequest() {
    return $this->request;
  }
  public function getType() {
    return $this->type;
  }
}
```

I'm either missing something in creating this new Event or maybe there is something specific I need to do when adding Events to an existing and enabled module.

EDIT: Not really an answer, so I'm putting it here.  I went ahead and implemented the EventSubscriber like the Event existed.  Once I did that and cleared the cache (again) the event was showing in both `drupal event:debug` and web profiler.